How to override the price of a catalog item in Paddle Billing while integrating it using their API?
In Paddle Classic there is an option for overriding the price of a catalog item if I want to apply a discount/coupon. So that I didn't have to create a discount/coupon in my merchant account. But in Paddle Billing there is no option for price overriding for catalog items. I must create a discount/coupon in my merchant account and pass the created discount_id in Paddle.Checkout.open(). Is there any alternate way to do it? I saw their API but there is no alternate way to do it as we can do it on Paddle Classic. My only option is to create a discount coupon in the merchant account and provide the discount_id Paddle.Checkout.open(). But I don't want that. Is there any alternate way to do it? Am I missing something?
